Can't connect Visual Studio 2022 to MacOS Sequoia due to Mono Installation fail
After upgrading my Mac to Sequoia today when I attempted to connect through Visual Studio 2022 on my windows PC the process errors out at 'Checking Mono Installation' with the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
On my Mac I've also upgraded Xcode, installed iOS 18, and reinstalled mono. I have restarted both devices, removed my Mac and recreated the connection. There is a dev post from a few months ago that deals with this same error, but it looks like it's back again.
Any workarounds or is this something we will have to wait for Microsoft to fix?

You can try to update your VS the latest version and try again.

If it still doesn't work, please try the solution given by community here.

That solution only partially resolves the issue, you can get past the mono verification but you can't debug, which is what we're trying to do.

It ended up being a Xamarin webservices issue that was resolved by Microsoft this morning. It seems to be a repeating issue. It had nothing to do with upgrading to Seqouia
